# lmer for removing batch dependency in one group

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am looking for a way to investigate whether a new batch is different from all previous batches. We measure around 40 parameters and each batch has 3 to 4 replicate values per parameter.

The data would look something like this:

```
x <- <- runif(30)
group <- c("ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "test", "test", "test","ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "ref", "test", "test", "test")
batch <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5) 
para <-  c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

            x batch group para
1  0.06211003     1   ref    1
2  0.98068602     1   ref    1
3  0.43039630     1   ref    1
4  0.20469014     2   ref    1
5  0.33930694     2   ref    1
6  0.59437157     2   ref    1
7  0.74482488     3   ref    1
8  0.67339357     3   ref    1
9  0.95111687     3   ref    1
10 0.07557358     4   ref    1
11 0.58379469     4   ref    1
12 0.88508711     4   ref    1
13 0.42175782     5  test    1
14 0.46646653     5  test    1
15 0.04820422     5  test    1
16 0.52352510     1   ref    2
17 0.33941331     1   ref    2
18 0.04024945     1   ref    2
19 0.82348698     2   ref    2
20 0.32724410     2   ref    2
21 0.20687205     2   ref    2
22 0.56888497     3   ref    2
23 0.44054675     3   ref    2
24 0.85070658     3   ref    2
25 0.56651205     4   ref    2
26 0.46701348     4   ref    2
27 0.34169127     4   ref    2
28 0.73738162     5  test    2
29 0.61114658     5  test    2
30 0.33163246     5  test    2


[![!\[x][1]][1]
```

I am thinking of using a lmer model here, as the samples in x are not randomly selected, but clearly have a dependency on batch.

Would a model like this tell me the right answer: Is Test different from Ref? Would it be beneficial to do a test for each parameter to know if test is different in one of them?
Is the Singular warning due to the test group containing only 1 batch?

```
> library(lme4)
> library (lmerTest)

> fit <- lmer(x ~ group + (1|batch) + (1|para))

boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular') 

> summary(fit)

Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: x ~ group + (1 | batch) + (1 | para)

REML criterion at convergence: 11.2

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.59726 -0.55181 -0.06342  0.57208  1.99818 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 batch    (Intercept) 0.008526 0.09234 
 para     (Intercept) 0.000000 0.00000 
 Residual             0.068891 0.26247 
Number of obs: 30, groups:  batch, 5; para, 2

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  0.50090    0.07073  3.00000   7.082  0.00579 **
grouptest   -0.06480    0.15815  3.00000  -0.410  0.70950   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
          (Intr)
grouptest -0.447
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg2VE.png
```